# Update Adempiere Jasper Report Libraries

Tags: java, jasper-reports, adempiere

I am getting classdef not found error in Adempiere, when i run report compiled in iReport 5.5.1,  I know the solution to this is updating Adempiere Jasper Libraries in the jboss. But i dont know which is the main folder i should copy paste the required jars.

Could anyone guide me in updating the Jasper Libraries such that it runs the new reports compiled in Ireport 5.1+ versions!

Answer (score 0):

When you run RUN_setup or RUN_silentsetup (if you've already configured the Adempiere properties files), the process should package, sign and deploy and jars in the ADEMPIERE_HOME/lib folder to jboss.

Though usually deploying newer versions of libraries is not as straight forward as just replacing the jar... it could be but not usually.

Replacing the libraries in an adempiere development environment and attempt to rebuild Adempiere to determine if there are any side effects. The libraries are located in the adempiere/JasperReportsTools/lib folder of the source